# Unexpected intermittent requests from IE 8 in MVC 3 system

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, internet-explorer-8

We have a system developed in ASP.NET MVC 3 using C#, razor views and view templates. Each controller is mapped as "/Controller/Action". Normally, one click results in one request towards a controller, with one response produced from View() in each controller. Works great.

Now to the exception. When running this in IE8 on XP, something rather strange happens. Occationally after having requested a controller (e.g. "/Controller1/Action"), the browser sends one additional request ("/Controller2/"), without any clear reason for doing so. This results in an unplanned call to a controller which I really cannot see any reason for, and it only happens in IE8/XP. Not IE9/Win7, Firefox, Chrome etc. And only intermittently.

Does anyone know of a bug that might result in this behaviour and/or a workaround for the problem?

Regards,

Michael

Comment: Do you have javascript on your page?

Comment: I had a similar issue, which was caused by dodgy javascript - that's why Darin is probably asking. There certainly isn't a problem with MVC and IE8 itself.

Comment: Yes we do have javascript of various kinds. Is there any particular type of javascript that you are thinking of that may be causing it?

Answer (score 2):

Aside from possible ajax requests. Check your rendered HTML for two things:

1- **a** with empty **href** attribute

2- **img** with empty **src** attribute

Examples:

```
<a href="">Click me</a>

<img src="" alt="image"/>
```

IE will make a second request to the same page when faced with these two examples.

Comment: This does in fact sound like it might be causing it. Haven't been able to verify yet but it sums up well with an IMG tag in the affected page that indeed doesn't have any src data. Thanks a million :-)

Comment: I have been following this and hope it solves your problem. If it does, please kindly mark the answer as correct.

Comment: I would (since I'm a newbie here I guess that means clicking the arrow to indicate that it's useful), but it won't let me since I don't have enough cred: "Vote Up requires 15 reputation".